# English phrase for "behatzlacha"

Tags: secular-culture

Is there a pithy phrase in English that captures the meaning of "behatzlacha"? My sense is that "good luck" has a different meaning, because it implies that luck, rather than, God, runs the world. "With success" is a direct translation, though I'm not sure if it's considered a common phrase in English.

Comment: "Good luck" is anyway more like "mazal tov".

Comment: May success be with you?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/She%27ll_be_right

Answer (score 1):

When speaking in English, I would say:

**I wish you much success**

Comment: Is this a common English phrase?

Comment: According to Google, this is a common English phrase.